# How to protect web.config connection string from other developers?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I have a requirement to protect my `Web.config` file from malicious users accessing our webserver & junior developers in team. I have used `RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider` to successfully encrypt & decrypt our file. However, decypting the connection string is as easy as accessing it from withing my application, no matter if it is encrypted or not

```
protected void btnShowConnectionString_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblMessage.Text = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyTestConnection"].ConnectionString;
}
```

How do I secure my connection string to avoid work arounds like these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this with standard solutions.

To do such protection you should write your own wrapper around standard library using this connection string, that will decrypt connection string from webconfig. 
And you should protect your wrapper from decompiling with something like Sentinel Hasp. If you don't protect your wrapper it will be simple to get encryption algorithm and decrypt connection string.

But it will be simpler to do not write production connection strings to developers webconfig. Use developer enviroment for developing and write production enviroment connection strings when deploying to production enviroment.

Answer (score 1):

You can read this link about `secure string connection`, recommended solution by msdn

link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the "workaround" you are mentioning isn't really a workaround, rather, it is what it is.

Your application (web or otherwise), must be able to decyrpt the information so that i can actually make the connection. Unless you are using Windows Authentication to your SQL server, user/pwd are always "there"...the nagging question I have is why/how would such code exist in your application (in the first place)?

As noted above in previous answers, separate your development environment from production - perhaps only have production config [transforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx) in production environment.

Comment: To go to sql using Windows authentication you should start application pool of IIS from special user that has rights on sql. It is not good practice. Or you should impersonate iis when it goes to db with user credentials. It is system administrators horror (double hope impersonation etc.)

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov Unsure of your environment, but that's not always true (domain servers, same server). Either way, the concept of a "user" exists that needs to be authenticated for access. with SQL auth, you will always have user/pwd data in the "clear" (one way or the other, as the above code shows). You can add SSL to your SQL connections, but will still not "hide" things at the application level.